# Match a comma followed by a newline with a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a comma delimited list I want to import into a database, and in some cases the last item is blank:

```
item1, item2, item3
item1, item2,
item1, item2,
```

I'd like to replace all of these empty columns with a placeholder value using a regexp

```
item1, item2, item3
item1, item2, PLACEHOLDER
item1, item2, PLACEHOLDER
```

I tried this:

```
preg_replace("/,\n/", ",PLACEHOLDER\n",$csv);
```

...but it isn't working. Anyone know what regexp would work for this?

Comment: You should check the `fgetcsv` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`preg_replace("/,\s*$/m", ", PLACEHOLDER\n", $csv);` should do it. This pattern matches a comma, followed by any number of spaces, followed by the end of the line, and replaces it with your placeholder text.

Comment: Maybe ? instead of * in case there isn't any whitespace: preg_replace("/,\s?$/m", ", PLACEHOLDER\n", $csv);

Comment: Your regexp did the trick Alex, thanks! The simpler regexps like /,$/m weren't working for me.

Comment: @Purpletoucan - Alex's \s* is better IMHO since it allows 0 or more spaces whereas \s? only allows 0 or 1.

Comment: @Purpletoucan: See James' comment. The `\s*` pattern matches 0 or more whitespace characters, whereas `\s?` would only match 0 or 1. You may have been thinking of `\s+`, which will match 1 or more, but not 0.

Comment: Yes sorry - ignore my comment...hole in the head moment ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/,$/m", ", PLACEHOLDER", $csv);
```

Use `$` along with the `m` modifier. `$` is the "end of line" anchor and `m` enables multiline mode.

> #### [m (PCRE_MULTILINE)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)
>
> By default, PCRE treats the subject string as consisting of a single "line" of characters (even if it actually contains several newlines). The "start of line" metacharacter (`^`) matches only at the start of the string, while the "end of line" metacharacter (`$`) matches only at the end of the string, or before a terminating newline (unless `D` modifier is set). This is the same as Perl. When this modifier is set, the "start of line" and "end of line" constructs match immediately following or immediately before any newline in the subject string, respectively, as well as at the very start and end. This is equivalent to Perl's `/m` modifier. If there are no `\n` characters in a subject string, or no occurrences of `^` or `$` in a pattern, setting this modifier has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid inserting blank lines, as well as capturing an incomplete list on the final line, the regex needs to provide an alternative like this:

```
$csv = preg_replace('/(?:,\s*[\r\n]+)|(?:,\s*$)/', ", PLACEHOLDER\n", $csv);
```